# Validaciones de campos en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, validación

Estoy aprendiendo y hace poco en una aplicación de escritorio con la que trabajamos en el salón entramos en el tema de las validaciones.

Se nos enseñó algo como esto:

```
if(textbox.text == "" ){
  MessageBox.Show("hacen falta campos por llenar")
}
```

Este es un ejemplo que hicimos en clase *en si es mas largo*, pues había que validar un formulario de un punto de venta, el cual tiene muchos mas campos que validar.

Mi pregunta es: ¿existe alguna forma de ahorrar código y hacer las validaciones mas simple?.

Tengo entendido que es posible, pero no se cómo hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Es una aplicación de escritorio? Hay una forma de automatizarlo pero para sitios web hechos en MVC. Para Windows Forms, si hay muchos campos, utilizaría un método genérico y una lista de controles a validar.

Comment: si es una app de escritorio olvide mencionarlo

Comment: aqui le va todo que se requiere como requisitos para enganchar en el languaje de programacion c#. - validadcion txtBox
- validacion conboBox
- leer archivo excel - manejando la libreria npoi

Answer (score 16):

En principio la validación debes hacerla control a control, ya que para cada uno las validaciones pueden ser diferentes (además de comprobar que el textbox no está vacio, podrias comprobar tambien que la entrada es un numero,por ejemplo). La forma habitual es suscribirse a los eventos `Validating` y `Validated` del control y realizar ahi la validación.

Por otro lado, en lugar de utilizar un `MessageBox`, lo mejor es añadir un `ErrorProvider` a tu formulario, y en el caso de que la validación del control falle añadir el error ahi. Sería algo asi:

```
private void textbox_Validating(object sender,System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
     if(textbox.text == "" )
     {
         e.Cancel = true;
         textbox.Select(0, textBox1.Text.Length);
         errorProvider1.SetError (textBox1,"Debe introducir el nombre");
     }
}

private void textBox1_Validated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(textbox, "");
}
```

Esto hace que en el momento en el que el `TextBox` pierda el foco se valide el campo, y si no es correcto aparece un simbolo de error al lado indicando el problema.

Si lo que quieres es que todos los controles se validen al pulsar un botón (por ejemplo, al guardar la ficha) lo que debes hacer es poner la propiedad `AutoValidate` del formulario a `Disabled`,por ejemplo poniendo esto en el constructor del formulario:

```
this.AutoValidate = System.Windows.Forms.AutoValidate.Disable;
```

Luego, en el botón de guardar, el código sería algo asi:

```
private void buttonGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{
    if (this.ValidateChildren(ValidationConstraints.Enabled))
    {
            //Todo es correcto, guardamos los datos
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Faltan algunos campos por rellenar");
    }
}
```

Para que esto funcione tienes que haber hecho en todos los controles lo que te indique antes de `Validating`y `Validated`

Espero que esto te ayude.

**Edit**

Para incluir lo que comenta @PabloSimonDiEstefano, el ejemplo que pongo en mi respuesta trata con un solo `TextBox`. Si se quisieran validar varios con el mismo código, primero habría que apuntar todos los eventos `Validating` de todos los `TextBox` al mismo manejado, y en él obtener lo primero que `TextBox` lo originó:

```
private void textboxes_Validating(object sender,System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
     TextBox tb = (TextBox) sender;
     if(tb.text == "" )
     {
         e.Cancel = true;
         tb.Select(0, tb.Text.Length);
         errorProvider1.SetError (tb ,"Debe introducir el nombre");
     }
}

private void textboxes_Validated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox) sender;
    errorProvider1.SetError(tb, "");
}
```

Comment: Solo una cosa, dentro del método textbox_Validating, lo primero tendrías que hacer TextBox tb = (TextBox) sender; y dentro de ese método utilizar tb en vez de textbox, ya que textbox es el nombre de una caja de texto en particular y estaríamos camprobando siempre el mismo objeto.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano tu podrias optimizar ese codigo?

Answer (score 5):

Podrías crear un control propio que herede el control a validar, y programarle un metodo de validacion.

Ejemplo:

```
public class MiTextBox : TextBox 
{
    public bool EsValido() 
    {
        // El método IsNullOrWhiteSpace devuelve TRUE cuando el parametro string pasado es NULL o tiene una cadena de caracteres de espacios o vacía.
        // Usamos el operador ! para invertir el bool devuelvo. 
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Text);
    }
}
```

Una vez creado tu control, podés compilar el proyecto y te aparecerá en la ToolBox.

Usa esto como text box, en del que viene, y para las validaciones solo tenés que llamar al método:

```
//Si EsValido devuelve false, mostrar el MessageBox
if(!textbox.EsValido())
{
   MessageBox.Show("hacen falta campos por llenar")
}
```

Deberás tener en cuenta que en tu método, podés hacer todas las validaciones que creas convenientes.

De esta forma creas un control que puedas reutilizar.

Answer (score 1):

si quieres hacerlo todos de golpe, osea tienes 1000 textbox en un formulario (exagero, sabes...) y para validarlos es un mundo... puedes hacer esto. Crea un metodo asi.

```
 bool validarTextBoxs()
    {
        foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
        {
            try
            {
                if (item is TextBox)
                {
                    //Codigo comprobacion  de textbox
                    if (item.Text == "")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Hay campos vacios");
                        item.Focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else if (item is RichTextBox)
                {
                    //codigo comprobacion de richtextbox
                    if (item.Text == "")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Hay campos vacios");
                        item.Focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else if (item is ComboBox)
                {
                    if (item.Text == "")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Debes seleccionar un item");
                        item.Focus();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Suerte!

Comment: para que se utilizo el try cath de tu codigo ? y gracias por la ayuda ya me doy una mejor una idea

Comment: El try y catch, es por si alguna conversión devuelve un error (campos personalizados, errores internos, etc).

Comment: como podria hacer lo mismo pero validando solo numeros ?